# Azure Easy Tables - Check if row exists

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to check if row exists in Azure Easy Tables by using `table.Where(item => item.Name == Entry.Text)`
Then I am checking if List where I save it is null or not. But table still return something so this is not working.
Should I use other code or is there some way to check if row exists and return bool ?

Comment: This might help you to change the logic.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28667601/get-the-azure-table-row-count

Comment: Thank you this works! I changed it that I am now checking count of entities what it returns.

Comment: But there is one very weird bug. I run it on mobile emulator and it works fine. But when I run it on tablet emulator it is not working. It always return 0 as count of found rows which on mobile emulator is 1. I checked the internet connection. Is something wrong with emulator ? Emulators both with same Android version.

Comment: upvote the answer if it works. Please post a new question for mobile emulator issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Way to do it:**

```
List<Entity> Entities = new List<Entity>();
Entities = await table.Where(entity => entity.Name == "name");
var count = Entities.Count();
```

Then check if the **count** value isn't equal to 0 and you good to go.